# Borrow problems with compiled SQL statements

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

My program uses rusqlite to build a database from another data source. The database builds multiple tables in the same manner, so I thought I'd make a reusable function to do so:

```
fn download_generic<Inserter>(table_name: &str,
                              connection: &mut rusqlite::Connection,
                              inserter: &mut Inserter)
                              -> Result<(), String>
    where Inserter: FnMut(&str, &json::JsonValue) -> ()
{}
```

`inserter` is a function that binds the correct values from a previously-prepared statement and does the insertion.

I call it like this:

```
let mut insert_stmt = connection
    .prepare("insert or replace into categories values(?,?);")
    .unwrap();

download_generic("categories",
                 &mut connection,
                 &mut |uuid, jsonproperties| {
                     insert_stmt.execute(&[&uuid, &jsonproperties["name"].as_str().unwrap_or("")]);
                 });
```

However I can't pass `&mut connection` to `download_generic` because it's already being borrowed by the `insert_stmt`. Putting it into a `RefCell` makes no sense because I shouldn't need runtime overhead to make this work.

I could try making the `insert_stmt` generated by a lambda that you pass to `download_generic`, but then I get overwhelmed by having to add lifetime markers everywhere, and it seems unnatural, anyway.

Comment: Putting it in a `RefCell` wouldn't work: `RefCell` simply checks at run-time instead of compile-time but the same underlying check is performed => **Aliasing XOR Mutability**. The obvious question is: can't you just borrow (immutably) the same connection? If a single required borrow is mutable, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Can't I just move insert_stmt into the lambda somehow so that `download_generic` keeps it?

Comment: Could you use `prepare_cached` instead of `prepare` to get a prepared statement within the closure instead? You'd have to pass `connection` to the closure explicitly to avoid conflicting borrows.

Comment: @FrancisGagné well, that is actually a helpful suggestion and solves my problem in this case, but my question is more of a Rust idiom question; also, using the cache from rusqlite will cause the performance disadvantage of having to look up the query in the cache list.

Comment: I'd suggest providing a generic (no non-std deps), minimal reproduction of the issue and use that as your example, or, link to a gist. It would make it easier for others to reproduce your issue and work out solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, Rust prevents you from having an immutable borrow and a mutable borrow on the same object active at the same time. This is to prevent dangling pointers and data races.

In rusqlite's API, some methods on `Connection` require a mutable `self`, and some methods only require an immutable `self`. However, some of the methods that only require an immutable `self` return objects that keep that borrow active; `prepare` is an example of this. Therefore, as long as one of these objects stays in scope, Rust will not allow you to take a mutable borrow on the `Connection`.

There's probably a reason why some methods take `self` by mutable reference. Requiring a mutable reference ensures the callee that it has exclusive access to that object. If you think that might not be the case for the methods you need to use, or you think there could be another way to solve this, you should report an issue to the library's maintainers.

Regarding `prepare` specifically, you can work around the conflicting borrows by calling `prepare_cached` from within the closure instead. In order to do that, you'll have to make `download_generic` pass the `connection` back as a parameter to the closure, otherwise you'd have two mutable borrows on `connection` and that's not allowed.

Comment: `Connection::prepare` accepts a non-mutable `&self`, and thus I can pass the prepared `Statement` around along with the `Connection` itself. Consequently, this problem is trivially solvable.

Comment: "This is to prevent dangling pointers and data races" actually not. Its a perf decision, it allowed the emission of 'no_alias' to the llvm backend. This results in better optimization. Once they chose to say 'no_alias' then you had to make sure it was true. In a parallel universe there is a rust lang where they took the opposite decision and allowed aliasing and take the perf hit (just like all other C like languages). You can opt into that perf mode by saying 'restrict' in c and c++

Comment: @njaard - and what is the trivial solution. I feel this is like fermats last theorm, "I have a solution but this margin is too small"